# Compare Django ValuesListQuerySet elements to List elements

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have two variables:

```
var1 ex: [6, 2, 4, 5] type: ValuesListQuerySet
var2 ex: ['4', '2'] type: List
```

I must compare the elements of these two variables , the result should be:

```
['4', '2']
```

My code:

```
idmatch = []
for r in var1:
    for k in var2:
        if k == r:
            print("here")
            idmatch.append(str(k))
```

The two elements are never the same , and the result is:

```
[]
```

How can i compare them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ValuesListQuerySet` contains integers, but your list contains strings.

If you are not concerned about the order, the easiest solution is to convert both variables to sets.

```
# convert var1 to a set of strings
var1 = set(str(x) for x in var1)
# convert var2 to a set
var2 = set(var2)
idmatch = var1 & var2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is not queryset vs list, but the content of those; one has integers, the other has strings.